# Integrating PayPal with an Android app, without requiring users to have a PayPal account

Tags: android, paypal

I'm developing an Android app, in which users enter and (securely) save their credit card information.  I'd then like users to have the option of making payments via PayPal.  If the user has a PayPal account, it seems quite simple, but some users won't.  Is it possible to make a PayPal payment using the stored credit card information rather than by having the user sign in to PayPal?

Thanks, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: No, there is no way to do such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to PayPal's website, ["your buyers don't need a PayPal account"](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/compare-business-products).  Specifically looks like you could use the [Direct Payment API](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Merchant/merchant/DCCIntro-outside).

Comment: @Greg Note that using PayPal in an app distributed on the Android Market/Play Store may be against the Google terms of use.